# LINQ to SQL Lookup table? Join perhaps? I'm lost... ;/

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Not sure if this is called a lookup table... Here's a screenshot of the schema: [http://apoads.com/db-schema.png](http://www.apoads.com/db-schema.png)

What I want to do is join the Ad and MilBase table where the MilBase.BaseID is a given value. In the result, I'd like to be able to access the data like so: ad.MilBase.BaseName, etc...

I just can't seem to wrap my mind around this right now... ;/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your schema has the semantics of a many-to-many relationship between Ad and MilBase and as such the really desired way you would be wanting to do this in LINQ would be ad.Milbases which would then hold a Collection of Milbases.

The problem is not made any better by the fact that LINQ To SQL does not support many-to-many relationships directly, and in reality (assuming that your lookup table only defines a one-to-one or one-to-many relationship) you'd have to do something like

```
ad.Adbases.Single().MilBase
```

Of course assuming there will always be one - if that's not the case, then you've got some more complicated things ahead of you.

Of course a join is also always possible too - either way - if this is not the information you were looking for, could you clarify the relationship between Ad and Milbase? (many-to-many, etc?). Also - if this is not a many-to-many and you are able to do so, I would really change this to be a foreign key in either Milbase or the Ad table.

EDIT: In response to your comment,

You could do something like

```
var query = from a in db.ad
            select new {
               a.property1,
               a.property2,
               ...
               Milbases = a.Adbases.Select(s => s.Milbase)
            };
```

Obviously that code won't compile, but it should give you a rough idea - also I'm certain it can be done in better ways, but something like that should work.

Comment: The relationship I'm looking to create is that one ad could be in many bases. 

That could be for many ads... is my schema wrong in this instance? Should this not be a many-to-many relationship?

Comment: If you are wanting to have the relationship where one ad can be in many bases (as you said) and where many bases can contain many ads (i didn't quite get if this was what you tried to explain) then yes, your above stated schema is correct.

Comment: Oh also - I do believe the general term for your "lookup" table would be a mapping table - as it describes the mapping(s) between ad and milbase.